# Как реализовать функцию, высчитывающую проценты js через разбиение массива по множественным разделителям

Tags: javascript

```
function calc_percent(){
    let arr = input.value;
    let first_num = arr.split(/_(.+|-|*|/)/)[0];// цифры, введенные до одного из разделителей (+, -, *, /)
    let second_num = arr.split(/_(.+)/)[1];//цифры, введенные после любого активного разделителя(например -)
    let percent = first_num/100*second_num;// процент
    input.value = percent;// вывод данных по нажатию на кнопку %  <button type = "button" class = "second_row" onclick = "calc_percent()">%</button>
}
```

Как сделать, чтоб первое число формировалось до  любого из указанных разделителей и второе число после этого разделителя? И как найти процент, например, 100 - 10%  или 100 + 10%? Выше есть код, но там проблемы с регулярными выражениями...
В общем, это попытка создать калькулятор... в один инпут должно вводится число. например 100, потом от него должны отниматься желаемые проценты, например 10 и по нажатию на кнопку % должно произойти вычисление этих процентов и вывод их в тот же инпут, как результат. то есть, мы принимаем в этом инпуте массив с числами, разделенными некоторыми знаками. например 100-10%, так вот, надо как-то разделить этот массив на два числа и совершить с ними операцию по вычислениею процентов. не судите строго,  я только начинаю изучать js...

Comment: Я не понял вопроса, к сожалению, но проблема с первой регуляркой может быть в том, что не экранирован знак деления, который без этого воспринимается как окончание регулярки. И знак умножения тоже нужно экранировать, иначе он становится квантификатором. Нужно так: `/_(.+|-|\*|\/)/`

Comment: Ещё одна проблема в том, что `.+` означает «сколько угодно символов кроме перевода строки», поэтому после него все остальные альтернативы в скобках бессмысленны, они подпадают под сочетание `.+`. Разве что вы имели в виду «любой символ со знаком плюс», тогда плюс тоже нужно экранировать: `.\+`.

Comment: А почему вы всегда считаете first_num/100*second_num;  независимо от знака, который стоит в выражении?

Comment: Вам стоит переформулировать вопрос. Опишите детальнее контекст и задачу. Насколько можно понять, у вас форма, куда вводятся данные, которые нужно вычислить. Предоставьте примеры таких данных и требуемый результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение, в котором создать три группы в скобках: для числа, для знака и для количества процентов. Затем использовать условное ветвление в зависимости от знака. (Я не добавлял проверки на правильность входных данных).

```js
function calc_percent(){
  const str = input.value;
  let result;
    
  let [, num, operator, percent] =
    str.match(/(\d+)\s*([-+*/])\s*(\d+)%/) ?? [];
    
  num = Number(num);
  percent = num / 100 * percent;
    
  if (operator === '-') result = num - percent;
  else if (operator === '+') result = num + percent;
  else if (operator === '*') result = num * percent;
  else if (operator === '/') result = num / percent;
  else result = 'Неправильный формат.';
    
  input.value = result;
}
```

```html
<input id='input'>

<button type = "button" class = "second_row" onclick = "calc_percent()">%</button>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. эта функция, предложенная вами - то, что нужно. как-то так изначально и задумывалось. к сожалению, не хватило знаний сделать это без помощи. но при использовании ее в коде возникла проблема. uncaught type error: object null is not iterable(cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.Iterator). насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что не читается некое свойство в строке с регуляркой (/(\d+)\s*([-+*/])\s*(\d+)%/); не могу понять где именно. посоветуйте, пожалуйста, руководство по регуляркам. хочется разобраться в них самостоятельно.

Comment: @coder56  Скорее всего ошибка происходит от того, что регулярка не подходит введённым данным. Например, перед знаком процента введён пробел или что-то в этом роде. Тогда match возвращает null и деструктурирование не может получить элементы `[, num, operator, percent]`. Я немного отредактировал код, чтобы вместо ошибок просто получались пустые (undefined) переменные, их нужно будет проверять.

Comment: @coder56  Про регулярки можно почитать в этом разделе популярного учебника: https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions Если читаете на английском, тогда лучше в английской версии, она чаще обновляется и исправляется: https://javascript.info/regular-expressions

Comment: @coder56 Если напишите пример входных данных, вызывающих ошибку, попробую исправить регулярку, чтобы она учитывала такой вариант.

Comment: function press(x) {
            input.value += x;
        } так выглядит функция выводящая содержимое кнопок на экран калькулятора и вот так html <button type = "button" class = "fifth_row" onclick = "press('1')">1</button> может, проблема в кавычках вокруг 1? кстати, болшое спасибо за ссылку на регулярки.

Comment: что касается входных данных, я просто ввожу цифры без пробелов. например, 100-10% или 100+10% и оба эти выражения не вычисляют значение, а возвращают "неправвильный формат".

Comment: @coder56 Что-то я совсем запутался) `function press...` — это как будто из какого-то другого вопроса. Что касается примеров ввода, я их тестирую в ответе и там всё в порядке (можно нажать кнопку «Выполнить код» и появится форма). Видимо, вы это используете в более сложном приложении и там, возможно, есть дополнительные источники трудностей.

Comment: str.match(/(\d+)\s*([-+*/])\s*(\d+)/) ?? []; спасибо огромное, добрый человек) лучи добра вам) вот так работает! я просто не ввожу в инпут сам знак процентов и в сообщениях выше он не нужен... Прошу простить мою невнимательность...

Comment: @coder56 Успешного и лёгкого обучения)